# String types not allowed (at 'spacing' with value '8db')

Tags: android

This is my first question. Beforehand, excuse my poor english. I want to ask you, because I have had problems with this bug for several days until now. Thanks. This line is in the file values.xml

`<dimen name="spacing">8db</dimen>`

Then, when the project is syncing with Gradle, it does appear this error.

```
String types not allowed (at 'spacing' with value '8db').
```

Help me, please. :)

Comment: Try `dp` instead of `db`.

Comment: It does not work. When I turn db into dp and then sync, it changes again to db. :/

Answer (score 1):

Here, you need to change "8db" to "8dp": `<dimen name="spacing">8dp</dimen>`

Comment: It does not work. When I turn db into dp and then sync, it changes again to db. :/

Comment: Add this and clean the project.    <dimen name="spacing">8dp</dimen>

Comment: can you post the full values.xml file, need to see it.

Comment: You need to grant me the access.

Comment: Ok Hassan. Thank you, man.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1WpAuxUj14qd1ZxbUdYeHB5MFE/view?usp=sharing)